# Can I see my balance without logging in?

Tags: seed, balances

Can I see my balance without logging in with my seed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The balance is **not stored on the seed** but on the addresses [created](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) from your seed.

So if you want to see your balance, you just need to know the addresses.

You can either look your balance up in your own full node or, if you don't have one you can use an online Tangle explorer like [thetangle.org](https://thetangle.org) or [iotasear.ch](https://iotasear.ch).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, with a tool like [My IOTA Balance](https://prizz.github.io/My-IOTA-Balance/) or [iotabalance.com](https://iotabalance.com/).

Comment: Just a note about iotabalance, there is no dedicated node for iotabalance (web version) yet... You can use the source from github as a portable tool which is a better way to use it IMO.

Comment: I use it locally, and it has fixes for the new api changes too.

https://github.com/iotaos/IOTABalance
Packaged up version as a release:
https://github.com/iotaos/IOTABalance/releases

You can set your own custom fullnode with it under 'settings', or pick a preferred one, or let it randomly query various nodes for your addresses one at a time. Hope some people enjoy it as I do.

Answer (score 2):

If your IOTA are spread across multiple addresses, in order to see your full balance you must have access to your seed, so it can retrieve every  single address.

If you have a list of addresses your IOTA are stored in, you can input them into a site like the following: https://iotasear.ch/

Keep in mind that if your IOTA are stored across multiple addresses, each address will only show a portion of your total balance.